# Как установить curl через ConEmu

Tags: curl, windows-7

На Windows требуется установить CURl.
 Скачал альтернативу терминала ConEmu. И как понял нужно в строке ввода ввести $ sudo apt-get install curl - далее, начнется скачивание. Но выдает[image: ...]

Что не так?

Answer (score 4):

Вы используете команды линукса в мире Виндоус где <s>у них нет силы</s> они не работают.
Мне приходилось использовать терминал [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/). У него единственного были табы.
Если вам необходим  curl для винды [скачайте его](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html) и просто запускайте из консоли, например так:

```
curl --head yandex.ru
```